# how to install python libraries on windows rt?

Tags: python, microsoft-metro, windows-rt

I'm running Windows rt, and I've got python 3 for metro installed.
Is it possible to install various python libraries like pygame etc?

Alternatively is it possible to download the source on x86 windows and re-compile it for ARM.

Or maybe run pygame in interpreted mode?

Comment: I believe it should be the same as what you do on a windows PC: 1) download the source zip file, 2) unzip it, 3) open admin command line, 4) cd to the source directory, 5) python setup.py install.